# How to reassign listener in onAttach of a fragment when parent is also a fragment instead of Activity?

Tags: android

I know that in order to reassign listener when a fragment is recreated and fragment's parent is an activity, we assign listener instance in following way:

```kotlin
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    if(context is MyListener){
       this.listener = context
    }
}
```

As far as I know this context always refers to an activity.

How would I achieve the same in case parent of frament is also a fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check to see if your parent fragment implements an interface, you should get access to the parent fragment via [`parentFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getParentFragment()) (or [`requireParentFragment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireParentFragment()) if you want an always non-null parent fragment).

```
fun onAttach() {
    val parent = parentFragment
    if (parent is MyListener) {
       this.listener = parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that casting to an interface is not one of the [recommended methods for communicating between fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) as it tightly couples your fragments together, making them much harder (if not impossible) to test in isolation. Consider using the [Fragment Result API to pass results between parent and child fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#pass-parent-child).